# Socket.io not being called from router

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to pass socket.io to a router and then emit a call from that router, but it never emits. I'm suspecting an issue in socket.io passing to the router.

how app.js looks:

```
//app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var logger = require('morgan');
var weather = require('./routes/weather');

server.listen(3000, function () {
    weather.refreshWeather();
    console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000');
});

app.use(logger('dev'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.use('/', weather.router(io));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

module.exports = app;
```

how weather.js looks:

```
//weather.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var returnRouter = function (io) {
    router.get('/weather', function (req, res, next) {
        console.log('About to emit!');
        io.sockets.emit('weather', {
            temperature : '12' // this is just a test value
        });
        res.render('weatherpage');
        next();
    });
    return router;
}

module.exports = {
router: returnRouter, // exports variable
refreshWeather : refreshWeather // exports function
}
```

and finally how jade looks:

```
//weatherpage.jade
doctype html
html
  head
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/index.css')
    title Dashboard
  body
    script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
    script.
      var socket = io();
      socket.on('weather', function(data){
      document.getElementById('weather').innerHTML = data.temperature
      });
```

Comment: It's really a design mistake to try to update a page you're about to render with socket.io. You're rendering a template, the page isn't loaded yet or connected yet via socket.io.  Don't use timers to hack around this.  Just include the initial data IN the template itself (that's why you use templates in the first place (so you can include data in them).  Don't use socket.io for the initial temperature value.  You can use socket.io for updated temperatures after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Socket.io is being called  fine. Your problem here is that the socket event is emitted and then you render the jade template! The event is long gone by the time the page renders. However, if you already have the page rendered, say in another browser window, you'll find those other pages get updated as you would expect.

If you have the weather data when rendering the weatherpage template, just template it normally and continue to listen to socket events to update the page after it is served.

The route handler that serves a page with a socket listener is almost never the place to emit socket events meant to be rendered on that same page. I suppose it makes sense if you want to update all your clients when that endpoint is hit.

Think about what you are doing. Where is the temperature changed data generated? You say every minute. That's the place to emit your socket events. Every rendered (already served)  weatherpage in a browser will be updated.

Comment: I have experimented with timer function and it works totally fine as long as I am doing it in app.js, my problem here is that I can't get the socket.io to function in router. Also I'm refreshing weather every minute and I wan't it to refresh on the website as well. Also I have tried putting the res.render before sockets.emit but result is the same.

Comment: @Shard - Eeeck.  Don't use a timer.  That's completely the wrong design solution.  You are hacking instead of solving the problem the right way.

Comment: @Shard Instead of passing io to every function whereever you want to use , just create wrapper module file for websocket and whenever you want to send message through socket just call send function of that wrapper file.So by doing this your all sockets related function will be in one file and it will be easy to manage also.

Comment: I actually llike explicitly passing dependencies in to each module on the constructor as it were.

Comment: @RobertMoskal im refreshing weather in weather.js but since the http request can take time, im just saving the weather to a variable once its done and then just use a timer to emit that variable to html. I'm a total beginner so any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

So following the advice of the user sarju I added this bit to my app.js

```
module.exports = function socketEmit(id,data){
    io.sockets.emit(id,data);
}
```

and this bit to my weather.js

```
require('../app')('weather', {
        temperature : temperature
    });
```

I'm not sure if this is the best or smartest way to do it, but it worked for me. If someone has a better suggestion I will gladly mark that as the correct answer.